# Where can I change my Ruby gems directory path in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to use `wicked_pdf` and `wkhtmltopdf`, but everytime I run it I get the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Error: Failed to execute: ["/home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--encoding", "utf-8", "--disable-javascript", "--disable-internal-links", "--disable-external-link...
```

I think the issue is that it's executing from the `/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/..` directory instead of my `/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/..`, but I can't seem to get it to switch tot he 2.5.1 directory.  I'm using `rvm` and it's currently set to 2.5.1 as seen here.  Where else would I need to check to change this?  I've also uninstalled and install all of my gems and bundler, but no luck.

```
daveomcd@mcdonald-PC9020:~/rails_projects/bane$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.3.4 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, I figured out the issue shortly after posting.  My issue was I was using it in conjuction with Sidekiq.  I needed to kill my sidekiq process and then restart the process.  I guess it had started up when I was on a separate project.  Thanks to anyone that took a look at my question.